# quadrilaterals, bisectors are parallel

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral, bisection

prove that in a quadrilateral ABCD with angle B=90 and D=90 the bisectors of A and C are parallel. 
ABCD is not a rectangle

Comment: What can you say about the angles at $A$ and $C$? What if, say, the bisector of $A$ intersects $BC$ in a point $P$? Can you compute the angle at $P$ in the triangle $ABP$?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You've now been here a week, and asked three good interesting questions. But you haven't shown any work of your own on any of them. The convention here is that you should do more than just ask for answers. Your question should show what you've done so far, and where you are stuck. (You should also accept (the check mark) an answer that works best for you and upvote (the up arrow) any that help. You can upvote more than one answer, and can upvote the one you accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum $A+C=180°$ so the sum of half of them is $90°$

This means that acute angle $E$ is half $A$ so bisectors are parallel because correspondent angles are congruent

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting explicitly what your picture shows: the quadrilateral is inscribed in a circle. In fact it might be nonconvex, with $B$ and $D$ in the same semicircle.

Answer (score 2):

This follows from sum of angles. You have that the sum of the angles $A$ and $C$ is $180$ so the sum of the angles of the bisectors is $90$. Together with the angle sum of a triangle the bisector of $C$ intersect the line through $A$ and $D$ with the same angle as the bisector at $A$.